# Create combobox in Excel to filter

Tags: excel, vba

Am new in stackoverflow. I am using VBA at work and i have a problem completing my task. I want to create a macro that creates in excel sheet a combobox then finds which cell the uses has select and feed the data of the column to combobox. If i do it with 2 macros (1. create comb 2. feed the data) works fine. If i try to united them in one does not work. Cannot find the combobox. 
Problem is line :    Sheet1.ComboBox1.AddItem Value
Here is my code. Thanks for any help that can be provided

```
Global mycellCl As String
Sub CreateComboBox1()
'first part
Lastrow = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", _
                Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=250, Top:=10, Width:=100, _
                Height:=20)
End With
myvalue = ""
'end sub
'2nd part works fine as 2nd macro FeedData()
Dim Lrow As Long, test As New Collection
Dim Value As Variant, temp() As Variant
ReDim temp(0)

mycellCl = Mid(Application.ActiveCell.Address, 2, 1)
'Lastrow = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

On Error Resume Next
temp = Sheet1.Range(mycellCl & "2:" & mycellCl & Lastrow).Value
For Each Value In temp
    If Len(Value) > 0 Then test.Add Value, CStr(Value)
Next Value
If Sheet1.Shapes.Count > 0 Then
For Each Value In test
    Sheet1.ComboBox1.AddItem Value
Next Value
End If
On Error GoTo 0
Set test = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't refer to the combobox as a member of the Sheet1 class since it doesn't exist at compile time. Simple solution is to store a reference to the combobox you add and use that variable:

```
Sub CreateComboBox1()
    Dim cbo                   As Object
    'first part
    Lastrow = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set cbo = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", _
                                         Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=250, Top:=10, Width:=100, _
                                         Height:=20).Object
    myvalue = ""
    'end sub
    '2nd part works fine as 2nd macro FeedData()
    Dim Lrow As Long, test    As New Collection
    Dim Value As Variant, temp() As Variant
    ReDim temp(0)

    mycellCl = Mid(Application.ActiveCell.Address, 2, 1)
    'Lastrow = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    On Error Resume Next
    temp = Sheet1.Range(mycellCl & "2:" & mycellCl & Lastrow).Value
    For Each Value In temp
        If Len(Value) > 0 Then test.Add Value, CStr(Value)
    Next Value
    If Sheet1.Shapes.Count > 0 Then
        For Each Value In test
            cbo.AddItem Value
        Next Value
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set test = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. When you say reference what do you mean. I am new in vda...

Comment: I mean the `cbo` variable in the version I posted.

Comment: Thanks 
difficult to view code from the phone scrren!!
It works fine